# What's wrong with my pdo mysql prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a pdo prepared statement that doesn't work. Can you please help me? I will include some code and the error.
Don't pay much attention to the included database.php file. It only stores variables needed for the new PDO.

```
include('mysql/database.php');
$dbcheck_email_validation=$_POST["email_validation_ajax"];
$dbcheck_email_validation=htmlspecialchars($dbcheck_email_validation);
$dbcheck_email_validation=mysql_real_escape_string($dbcheck_email_validation);
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?";
$query = $create_pdo->prepare($sql_query);
$query->execute(array($dbcheck_email_validation));
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row_from_query = $query->fetch();
$dbcheck_email_validation_assoc=$row_from_query['email'];
echo json_encode($dbcheck_email_validation_assoc);
```

And the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045]      Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in /home/letsrate/public_html/favorit/ajax/ajax_email_validation.php:6Stack trace:#0 /home/letsrate/public_html/favorit/ajax/ajax_email_validation.php(6): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=;dbn...', NULL, NULL)#1 {main} thrown in /home/letsrate/public_html/favorit/ajax/ajax_email_validation.php on line 6
```

Comment: This is a connection issue.. seems like your username and password is wrong.

Comment: Don't mix `PDO` and `mysql_`, use one or the other (and don't use `mysql_` as it is deprecated).

Comment: Using placeholders in a prepared statement will escape data for you. Don't mix it with anything like `mysql_real_escape_string`. Use `htmlspecialchars` when you are inserting data into an HTML document, not when you are inserting it into a database.

Comment: thank you very much. it was the connection issue, wrong pass.and yeah, I removed mysql strings.

Comment: are they just redundant when used with the PDO or can actually hinder the job performed by the PDO?

Comment: I'd _expect_ it to be redundant, but since it is a security issue I wouldn't risk it either.

Comment: @halfer your idea on this function's purpose is quite wrong. It has nothing to do with security

Comment: @YourCommonSense what do you mean?

Comment: I mean it's all right to remove a redundant function.

Comment: (Ah, sorry Oleg, I should have been more clear: by "I wouldn't risk it" I meant take the redundant function out!)

Comment: @halfer either way you are just *** <- put here whatever politically correct substitution for the word "wrong" that will suit you.

Comment: guys.. question.. how to check if the PDO was executed?

Comment: PDO always gets executed, unless server is down. Thus, there is no need to check. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: I meant how to check if it was executed correctly... there's an if condition that I want to locate after the execute in case it has been executed correctly and data was inserted in the table

Comment: if ($statement->execute())... thats what I have meant. will it return true/false?

Comment: why do you want such a condition? what you're going to do if query failed? Why do you think it will be executed incorrectly?

Comment: I want my script to send an email upon successful execution of the query.

Comment: then just send it after execute.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
  $dbcheck_email_validation=mysql_real_escape_string($dbcheck_email_validation);
```

You can't use `mysql` functions with PDO.

PDO does the escaping for you anyway, so there's no need for this.

Comment: Suppose upvoter can explain, how this comment does answer the question?

Comment: While it is a completely valid remark, it is not the answer OP is looking for, since this is not the point of failure.

Comment: Yeah the cause of failure was a connection problem

Answer (score 0):

just for sake of code DRYness

```
include('mysql/database.php');
$query = $create_pdo->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?");
$query->execute(array($_POST["email_validation_ajax"]));
echo json_encode($query->fetchColumn());
```

This is all the code you really need.